# Why was my edit rejected with a canned justification that doesn't seem to make sense?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I proposed [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24743364) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8235171/814422). In particular, I was editing a snippet of code which was prefixed with "If you run through the following code in Python 2.7 (or later)". The snippet will only work in Python 2.7, not any later version of Python, because the only versions of Python later than 2.7 are Python 3. This has been true from the day Python 2.7 came into existence, as it was intentionally from the start the last release of Python 2. Python 3 does not support the print statement nor the `except Exception, e:` syntax (replaced with `except Exception as e:`). That makes the wording in the answer *wrong*. However, 2 edit reviewers rejected my edit with the apparently canned justification

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

This justification doesn't make any sense to me. I did not change the intent of the answer. I changed the syntax of a snippet that said it should work on "Python 2.7 (or later)" so that it actually *does* work on Python 2.7 or later.

Why was my edit rejected? How can I improve it to meet the criteria?

Comment: Why not just mention all this in a comment? Seems like the user is relatively active. Then they could edit their own question if they deem it fit.

Comment: You could have also made the code match the text by removing the " (or later)".

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's not unreasonable, but is there an etiquette to favoring comments over edits?

Comment: @Don'tPanic That's not unreasonable either, but Python 2 goes EOL in less than a month, I figured a forward-thinking edit made more sense.

Comment: Basically, editing code is always a crapshoot. See [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/215552).

Comment: I don't know enough Python to comment on that, but I was just thinking it would have been a less risky edit suggestion.

Comment: For the record, when rejecting edits, reviewers are given [a list of rather constrained reasons to choose from](https://i.imgur.com/LjJymHY.png). If enough reviewers choose "reject", then edit gets rejected and the editor is presented with the reason chosen. It's not a perfect system, sometimes you do get situations where none of the pre-defined reasons *cleanly* applies and the free-form field is defined as "Causes harm" which is also not necessarily the case. So, it's a toss-up of writing a justification even if it doesn't necessarily "cause harm" or picking something that sort of applies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, you should write your own answer.

In my mind, because Python 2.x is going EOL, it doesn't make sense to support any documentation related to Python 2.x since that's not what people are going to be searching for.

The tools exist to write a sufficiently acceptable answer for Python 3.x, and I would encourage you to do so in this case.

It's a crap-shoot when editing code since many will interpret that as you changing the meaning (remember - the people reviewing your edit *may* not know the language), so it's better to strive for the cleaner option.

Comment: I just threw an upvote at [the answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47185863/814422) who long ago beat me to the punch. I will try a comment instead of an edit on the other answer.